# Calculate Average of boolean values

Tags: sql

I have seen a few examples but not many to boolean and been trying for hours and I cant get this to compile. I have a column called Status. In it is either 1 for true or 0 for false. I would just like to calculate the average percentage of uptime over downtime but keep hitting a wall.

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
declare @uptime float
declare @downtime float
declare @average float
Set @uptime = (select count(Status) AS Online  from dbo.[Uptimes] 
where Status=1)
print @uptime
Set @downtime = (select count(Status) AS Offline from dbo.[Uptimes]
where Status=0)




Select @uptime, CASE @downtime WHEN 0 THEN 100 ELSE @uptime / @downtime * 100
end
```

Comment: Do you hit any error running your query?

Comment: Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to allow people to replicate your issue. You should also tag your DBMS.

Comment: `@uptime / @downtime * 100` - you want up / total to get uptime. What exactly is “the problem”? Please edit the question to clarify

Comment: Are those uptimes recorded at a fixed interval? If not, then you might need to take a duration into account

Comment: If I add end in SQL then it runs fine otherwise it complains and wont let me use in a stored procedure.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes its done from a timer service. Records status of site to db every 3 seconds. then I am pulling to a progress bar. But it wont even let me save this as a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to modify the last statement to be a correct syntax using this format

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
declare @uptime float
declare @downtime float
declare @uptimeavg float

 

Set @uptime = (select count(Status) AS Online  from dbo.[Uptimes] 
where Status=1)

 

Set @downtime = (select count(Status) AS Offline from dbo.[Uptimes]
where Status=0)

 Set @uptimeavg = (@uptime / @downtime * 100)

Select (CASE WHEN @downtime = 0 THEN 100 ELSE  @uptimeavg END);


End
```